# How to convert HTML to XML, Import parsed XML to google sheets

Tags: html, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm using the following referenced here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service
to convert my HTML emails to XML, having trouble inserting it to google sheets.

```
// Create and log an XML representation of the threads in your Gmail inbox.
function createXml() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_mUz_byvewuIN-pToQArGjanK9IZQISxM9l5EogIbxU');
  var root = XmlService.createElement('threads');
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Catering");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)

    var msg = messages[j].getBody();
    var child = XmlService.createElement('thread')
        .setAttribute('messageCount', threads[i].getMessageCount())
        .setAttribute('isUnread', threads[i].isUnread())
        .setText(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject())
        .setText(msg);
    root.addContent(child);
  }
  var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
  var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
  var parsed = XmlService.parse(xml);
  ss.appendRow([parsed])
}
```

It throws the following:

`[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <threads/>]]`

Looking for guidance on setting the DOCTYPE, I do not have access to change the body of the emails.

The following is the HTML email i'm trying to process:

```
--===============3318764831337248603==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body style="font-family:arial, sans-serif; background-image:none" id="EmailC">
      <div class="c">
        <div class="cn-mailer">
          <div class="middle-content admin-users order-list-details order-view">
            <div class="middle-headline">
              <h1 style="background-color:#efefef; background-image:none; border:1px solid #CCC; font-family:arial; padding:3px 10px" bgcolor="#efefef">
                 Order <span>#70306391</span>
              </h1>
            </div>
             <div class="two-columns">
              <div class="right-middle form">
                <h2 style="background-color:#efefef; background-image:none; border:1px solid #CCC; font-family:arial; padding:3px 10px" bgcolor="#efefef">
                  Restaurant Details
                </h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
                    <p>
                      <label style="font-weight:bold">Restaurant Name</label>
                      <br>
                      <span>Catering</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
                    <p>
                      <label style="font-weight:bold">Restaurant Phone Number</label>
                      <br>
                      <span>236-2305</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                  <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
                    <p>
                      <label style="font-weight:bold">Restaurant Address</label>
                      <br>
                      <span>
                        1120 S. Michigan Ave
                        <br>
                        Chicago,
                        IL
                        60605
                      </span>
                  </p>
</div>
                  <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="two-columns">
              <div class="right-middle form">
                <h2 style="background-color:#efefef; background-image:none; border:1px solid #CCC; font-family:arial; padding:3px 10px" bgcolor="#efefef">
                  Customer Details
                </h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
                    <p>
                      <label style="font-weight:bold">Time of Order</label>
                      <br>
                      <span>Wed, May 27 02:25 PM</span>
                      <br>
                      <span>May 27, 2020</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
                    <p>
                      <label style="font-weight:bold">Requested Pickup Time</label><br>
                      <span>Sat, May 30 08:45 AM</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                  <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
                    <p>
                      <label style="font-weight:bold">Customer Name</label><br>
                      <span>Gianluca Pesce</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
                    <p>
                      <label style="font-weight:bold">Customer Phone Number</label><br>
                      <span>(313) 478-2671</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <span>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                    <div class="left" style="float:left; font-family:arial; padding:3px 5px; width:184px" width="184">
    <p>
      <label style="font-weight:bold">Order Type</label><br>
      <span>
        Pickup
         (Order for later)
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>

                  <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two-columns">
              <div class="right-middle form  top-margin details">
                <h2 style="background-color:#efefef; background-image:none; border:1px solid #CCC; font-family:arial; padding:3px 10px" bgcolor="#efefef">
                  Order Details
                </h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <ul style="font-family:arial;background-image: none">
                    <div class="item">
                      <div class="customer">
                        <h4>Gianluca Pesce</h4>
                      </div>
                          <table max-width: cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="order_item">
        <td>
            <strong id="ite_iq">3</strong>
        </td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>
            <strong>*Disposable Items</strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Set of 10</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$5.00</td>
        <td>ea.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"' colspan="2">
          * <b><u>CUSTOMER REQUESTED: pickup on Sat, May 30 at 8:45 AM</u></b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="order_item">
        <td>
            <strong id="ite_iq">1</strong>
        </td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>
            <strong>*Coffee Box</strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Regular</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$20.00</td>

      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>Coffee Choice</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Regular</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>Coffee Goodies</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>10 Coffee 12 oz Cups/Stir Sticks, 30 Creamers, 20 Sugars, 10 Truvia</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
      <tr class="order_item">
        <td>
            <strong id="ite_iq">1</strong>
        </td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>
            <strong>*Fresh Cut Fruit</strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Regular</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$32.00</td>

      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>Tongs</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>No</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
      <tr class="order_item">
        <td>
            <strong id="ite_iq">1</strong>
        </td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>
            <strong>*Cinnamon Roll French Toast</strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Regular</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$44.00</td>

      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>Sweet Specialty Goodies</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>1 tong, 10 butter, 1 12oz bottle syrup</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
      <tr class="order_item">
        <td>
            <strong id="ite_iq">1</strong>
        </td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>
            <strong>*Wraps</strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Regular</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$45.00</td>

      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>CYO - Ingredients</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Broccoli</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>spinach</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Sausage</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>CYO - Additional Ingredients</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Caramelized onion</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$5.00</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Swiss cheese</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$5.00</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>Wrap Condiments</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Small cup of Salas, small cup of Sour Cream, 2 small spoons</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>Tongs</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Yes</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
      <tr class="order_item">
        <td>
            <strong id="ite_iq">1</strong>
        </td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>
            <strong>*Buffalo Wrap</strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Regular</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$60.00</td>

      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><b>Tongs</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>No</td>
          <td style='"text-align:right;"'> - </td>

        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>--</td>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><strong>10% off orders over $0.50,
all day every day,
for a limited time only,
once per customer</strong></td>
        <td>($22.60)</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

                      <div style="width:400px;border-bottom:1px solid #444;margin:10px;"></div>
                          <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Item total:</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$226.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Discounts:</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>-$22.60</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Sub-total:</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$203.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Taxes/fees:</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>$23.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'>Tip/gratuity:</td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'>CASH TIP</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="grand_total">
        <td style='"text-align:left;min-width:150px;"'><strong>Grand Total:</strong></td>
        <td style='"text-align:right;"'><strong>$227.30</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

                    </div>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>

--===============3318764831337248603==--
```

Here is the Execution Transcript:

```
[20-05-29 10:16:19:810 CDT] Starting execution
[20-05-29 10:16:19:975 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.openById([1_mUz_byvewuIN-pToQArGjanK9IZQISxM9l5EogIbxU]) [0.157 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:283 CDT] GmailApp.getUserLabelByName([Catering]) [0.307 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:450 CDT] GmailApp.GmailLabel.getThreads() [0.166 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:608 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.getMessages() [0.158 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:770 CDT] GmailApp.GmailMessage.getBody() [0.161 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:770 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.getMessageCount() [0 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:771 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.isUnread() [0 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:771 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.getFirstMessageSubject() [0 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:20:931 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.getMessages() [0.159 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:21:083 CDT] GmailApp.GmailMessage.getBody() [0.151 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:21:083 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.getMessageCount() [0 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:21:084 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.isUnread() [0 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:21:084 CDT] GmailApp.GmailThread.getFirstMessageSubject() [0 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:21:253 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.appendRow([[[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <threads/>]]]]) [0.149 seconds]
[20-05-29 10:16:21:398 CDT] Execution succeeded [1.438 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Aerials I've edited the post and added the Execution Transcript to the bottom, it's not saying which line but I assume it's due to the XML not including the DOCTYPE declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue:

"Looking for guidance on setting the DOCTYPE, I do not have access to change the body of the emails."

> [Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: ]]

If you want to declare a DocType for the newly created Xml document you can do so by using the appropriate method(s) ( [setDocType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/document#setdoctypedoctype), [createDocType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#createdoctypeelementname) )

Once you declare the DocType though, you'll still have to work on your parsing because all you will append with the current code is the same string, but now with a DocType declared ;)

#### Here's a working example:

```js
function createXml() {
  // Get sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Create Xml document with root element "threads"
  var doc = XmlService.createDocument(XmlService.createElement('threads'));
  // Declare DocType "whatever-you-like" for the Xml document
  doc.setDocType(XmlService.createDocType('threads'));
  // Get the root element
  var root = doc.getRootElement();
  // Get some threads from Gmail
  var threads = GmailApp.getStarredThreads();
  // For each thread
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // Get messages
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    // And for each message
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++){
      // Get the plain html body
      var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();
      // Create a child element "thread"
      var child = XmlService.createElement('thread')
      // Set "messageCount" attr
      .setAttribute('messageCount', threads[i].getMessageCount())
      // Set "isUnread" attr
      .setAttribute('isUnread', threads[i].isUnread())
      // Set text attr
      .setText(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()+msg);
      // Add the child element to root
      root.addContent(child);
    }
    // Get prettyfied xml document
    var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(doc);
    // Log the prettyfied xml doc
    Logger.log(xml);
    // Create list of parsed children to append to sheet row
    var parsed = [];
    // Add the parsed text from children elements of root
    XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement().getChildren().forEach((child) => {parsed.push(child.getText())});
    // Append the row with parsed data
    ss.appendRow(parsed)
  }
}
```